# Which kind of big data framework can be used to achieve data transform in millisecond?

Tags: caching, bigdata, microservices, batch-processing, in-memory

In my application, which has Postgres database that contains 5 tables each has more than 1 million records and each table has more than 75 columns. My app query data from these tables and then transform data. transformation is currently done by scala scripts. Then these data serve to FronEnd. I am using microservice architecture having 3 microservices to do this. But querying and transforming data is time consuming like it takes more than 10 seconds.

Is there solution or big data frameworks that I can use to reduce this time to milliseconds ? Could it be able to communicate between microservice and database ?

Comment: You could look into Debezium and Kafka for pulling data out of the Postgres database and into a Kafka Streams transformer and into a KTable that could be embedded within a frontend application for sub-second K-V lookup

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, unless we are talking about 10s and 100s of milliseconds.

Long answer: generally if you need to process 75M data points transformed in milliseconds you:

- have to do it in-memory, carefully using your language's of choice data structures;
- pre-calc and cache the results with a risk that some (non-cached) requests will run for 10+ seconds;
- re-assess your technical requirements and/or architecture.

Comment: Yes. I am hoping to use in memory in order to mitigate time. I am think of Redis and Apache Ignite for storing in memory. Would that middleware be achieve this requirement ? Also How about integrating framework like Apache Flink to transform data ?

Comment: Most big data frameworks are mostly targeting horizontal scalability, not ultra-fast in-memory processing. I'd suggest to search for performance-optimised libraries, most likely to be found in a realm of high-frequency trading.